# grunt serve:dist or grunt build causing MIME error for some bower_components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, mime-types

OK I've tried to make sure this question hasn't be already asked, and I couldn't find it...so hopefully this is a first time for this question. My issue deals with using angular-fullstack generator and the grunt build or grunt serve:dist command. Both seem to have the same issue, they are copying over the bower_component files but then some of them seem to be having issues accessing them after the files are minified.

So here are the errors that come up from running grunt build. (note I'm suing spring-boot:run and have Maven execute the grunt tasks...but that seems to be working perfectly as far as I can tell):

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/plain:    "http://localhost:8080/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff". 5b26ecfc.vendor.js:2
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/". 5b26ecfc.vendor.js:20
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. (index):1
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/". 5b26ecfc.vendor.js:20
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/". 5b26ecfc.vendor.js:20
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. (index):1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined
```

I limited the main errors down to bootstrap's font use, and ckeditor. I discover someone else had a similar problem and addressed it by doing the following (at least for ckeditor): [ckeditor fix](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/CKEditor-problem-after-a-grunt-build) But I'm not completely happy with the solution as it would mean I would have to take similar steps with all of my bower_components that have other dependencies besides their js files. Here's my grunt file so you can see how it work:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Configurable paths for the application
    var appConfig = {
        app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client',
        dist: 'src/main/webapp'
    };

    // Load grunt tasks automatically, when needed
    require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
        useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
        ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
        cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn',
        protractor: 'grunt-protractor-runner',
        injector: 'grunt-asset-injector'
    });

//    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        yeoman: {
            // configurable paths
            client: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client',
            dist: 'src/main/webapp'
        },
        watch: {
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['wiredep']
            },
            injectJS: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.js',
                    '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                    '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
                    '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.js'],
                tasks: ['injector:scripts']
            },
            injectCss: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
                ],
                tasks: ['injector:css']
            },
            jsTest: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
                ],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'karma']
            },
            injectSass: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['injector:sass']
            },
            sass: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            livereload: {
                files: [
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.html',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.js',
                    '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                    '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images/{,*//*}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect().use(
                                '/client/bower_components',
                                connect.static('./client/bower_components')
                            ),
                            connect.static(appConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect.static('test'),
                            connect().use(
                                '/client/bower_components',
                                connect.static('./client/bower_components')
                            ),
                            connect.static(appConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }
            }
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '<%= yeoman.client %>/.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: [
                '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
            ],
            test: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
                ]
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.openshift',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/Procfile'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/'
                }]
            }
        },


        // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
        wiredep: {
            target: {
                src: '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html',
                ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.client %>/',
                exclude: [/bootstrap-sass-official/, /bootstrap.js/, '/json3/', '/es5-shim/', /bootstrap.css/, /font-awesome.css/ ]
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts/*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html'],
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
                flow: {
                    html: {
                        steps: {
                            js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                            css: ['cssmin']
                        },
                        post: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                root: 'client'
            }
        },
        // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css'],
            js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
                ],
                // This is so we update image references in our ng-templates
                patterns: {
                    js: [
                        [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
                }]
            }
        },

//        htmlmin: {
//            dist: {
//                options: {
//                    collapseWhitespace: true,
//                    conservativeCollapse: true,
//                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
//                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
//                    removeOptionalTags: true
//                },
//                files: [{
//                    expand: true,
//                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
//                    src: ['*.html', 'app/**/*.html'],
//                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
//                }]
//            }
//        },
//        uglify: {
//           dist: {
//             files: {
//               '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
//                 '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
//               ]
//             }
//           }
//        },

        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Allow the use of non-minsafe AngularJS files. Automatically makes it
        // minsafe compatible so Uglify does not destroy the ng references
        ngAnnotate: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/concat',
                    src: '*/**.js',
                    dest: '.tmp/concat'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Package all the html partials into a single javascript payload
        ngtemplates: {
            options: {
                // This should be the name of your apps angular module
                module: 'napiRest',
                htmlmin: {
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
                },
                usemin: 'app/app.js'
            },
            main: {
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
                src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
                dest: '.tmp/templates.js'
            },
            tmp: {
                cwd: '.tmp',
                src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
                dest: '.tmp/tmp-templates.js'
            }
        },

        // Replace Google CDN references
        cdnify: {
            dist: {
                html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/*.html']
            }
        },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'bower_components/**/*',
                        'assets/images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                        'assets/fonts/**/*',
                        'index.html'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/images',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images',
                    src: ['generated/*']
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        'package.json'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
                dest: '.tmp/',
                src: ['{app,components}/**/*.css']
            }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'sass'
            ],
            test: [
                'sass'
            ],
            dist: [
                'sass',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        },

        // Test settings
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
                singleRun: true
            }
        },

        mochaTest: {
            options: {
                reporter: 'spec'
            },
            src: ['server/**/*.spec.js']
        },

        protractor: {
            options: {
                configFile: 'protractor.conf.js'
            },
            chrome: {
                options: {
                    args: {
                        browser: 'chrome'
                    }
                }
            }
        },


        // Compiles Sass to CSS
        sass: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    loadPath: [
                        '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components',
                        '<%= yeoman.client %>/app',
                        '<%= yeoman.client %>/components'
                    ],
                    compass: false
                },
                files: {
                    '.tmp/app/app.css' : '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        injector: {
            options: {

            },
            // Inject application script files into index.html (doesn't include bower)
            scripts: {
                options: {
                    transform: function(filePath) {
                        filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
                        filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
                        return '<script src="' + filePath + '"></script>';
                    },
                    starttag: '<!-- injector:js -->',
                    endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
                        ['{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.js',
                            '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/app/app.js',
                            '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                            '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js']
                    ]
                }
            },

            // Inject component scss into app.scss
            sass: {
                options: {
                    transform: function(filePath) {
                        filePath = filePath.replace('/client/app/', '');
                        filePath = filePath.replace('/client/components/', '');
                        return '@import \'' + filePath + '\';';
                    },
                    starttag: '// injector',
                    endtag: '// endinjector'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss': [
                        '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}',
                        '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.{scss,sass}'
                    ]
                }
            },

            // Inject component css into index.html
            css: {
                options: {
                    transform: function(filePath) {
                        filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
                        filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
                        return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filePath + '">';
                    },
                    starttag: '<!-- injector:css -->',
                    endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
                        '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Used for delaying livereload until after server has restarted
    grunt.registerTask('wait', function () {
        grunt.log.ok('Waiting for server reload...');

        var done = this.async();

        setTimeout(function () {
            grunt.log.writeln('Done waiting!');
            done();
        }, 3000);
    });


    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'wait', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'injector:sass',
            'concurrent:server',
            'injector',
            'wiredep',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'wait',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run(['serve']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', function(target) {
        if (target === 'client') {
            return grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'injector:sass',
                'concurrent:test',
                'injector',
                'autoprefixer',
                'karma'
            ]);
        }

        else if (target === 'e2e') {
            return grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'injector:sass',
                'concurrent:test',
                'injector',
                'wiredep',
                'autoprefixer',
                'connect:test',
                'protractor'
            ]);
        }

        else grunt.task.run([
                'test:client'
            ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'injector:sass',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'injector',
        'wiredep',
        'useminPrepare',
        'autoprefixer',
        'ngtemplates',
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'rev',
        'usemin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

I'd be extremely happy if someone else out there found a way around this issue.

Comment: Also it should be noted that I already copied over all of the bower_components files, so the only difference between the answer given for Ckeditor (link) is that I haven't moved the script tag out of the injector section for grunt.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue ? I have a similar problem and I dont understand what's wrong...

Comment: Sadly no...unless you manually inject them yourself like I mentioned me doing with Ckeditor. We moved the manual inject part over to the grunt file though, and made some tasks to pull the files over and inject their includes into the main html file